# Lockdown docker network except the API gateway

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am building out a little micro service architecture, and I am stuck trying to build out the docker network. Basically I only want the API gateway to be accessible from outside of the network, every other service within it can not be hit directly from the outside. But, those services can be hit from other services within its network. Any advice on how to attack this? Very new to docker networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar use case where we were created two networks

Following is an example

```
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - external
      - internal

  backend:
    image: mysql
    port:
      - "3306":"3306" 
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  external:
    name: external
    driver: overlay
  internal:
    name: internal
    driver: overlay
```

We opened only port 80 and rest all worked on an internal network.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !